# Check if the text value is Newline in textbox

Tags: vb.net, char, newline, multiline

I have a textbox with multiline property. When verify the textbox, it will go through a function to check whether the value of each characters is in my allowed range. I have some value that have a newline such as below:

"Sorabee keeps your skin moisturizing last longer!

Description

Sorabee Skin Care series keep your skin moisture"

This is 3 sentences which has 3 newline. How to insert this newline in my checking as below:

```
Public Function AllowedChar(ByVal str As String) As Integer
    Dim cnt As Integer
    Dim allowChars As Char() = "1234567890QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNMqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm!+=-/., ?".ToCharArray()
    Try
        cnt = 0
        For Each ch As Char In str ' to check whether special character exist in a string
            If Array.IndexOf(allowChars, ch) = -1 Then
                cnt = cnt + 1
            End If
        Next
        Return cnt
    Catch ex As Exception
        strErrMsg = "Oops! Something is wrong with verify special characters at AllowedChar"
        MessageBox.Show(strErrMsg & vbCrLf & "Err: " & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Function
```

I can put a space to be verify. But how to put a newline as allowChars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a newline in a windows console application in Visual Basic, try this:

```
Console.WriteLine("hello", vbLf)
```

The vbLf makes a so called "Newline".

Comment: I'm using windows form. The textbox I mention in my post is like txtshopdetails. It will stores information about that shop, and for sure the is some newline. So I wanna make the newline as allow characters. See my 'Dim allowChars As Char()'. I can define a space. But not newline.. That is my problem

Comment: I do not quite understand what you would like to do, i'm sorry.

Comment: Assume you see "About Us" in many service website. The paragraph they write mostly have a newline or break </br> to move to next paragraph. When I do checking as my post above, how do I define a </br> in my textbox?

Comment: Why don't you use a Richtextbox? It's more easier.

Comment: Richtextbox? Is it differ from normal textbox? I want to eliminate the break. So the paragraph will become 1 paragraph regardless user insert more than 1 paragraph. Because the final view is limited its space on screen.. So i need to get rid of break.

Comment: A richtexbox is easier to use whit more amounts of texts, you can resize and adjust the font whatever you like.